Typing Itty Router Response in Cloudflare Worker
We are trying to have full typed Typescript API on Cloudflare worker. We are using Itty router for routing. The problem is Cloudflare's Response type doesn't offer that (doesn't accept generic or something in that manner).
Example code:
interface ApiResponseType { foo: string; }

helloRouter.get('/', (): Promise<Response<ApiResponseType>> => {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }));
});

We want to have something similar to above code - so to have the response body fully typed. How to achieve this? Thanks
